# cabal build fails with (conflict: requires GHC2021) it's unclear what this is?

Tags: haskell, cabal

```
cabal build myproject
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] next goal: plutarch (user goal)
[__0] rejecting: plutarch-1.3.0 (conflict: requires GHC2021)
[__0] fail (backjumping, conflict set: plutarch)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: plutarch
```

I'm running into the above error `(conflict: requires GHC2021)` however it is not clear what this is? It does not seem to be a package? There is various mentions of GHC2021 in a web search but I still don't understand what this conflict is?

https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/control.html seems to indicate it is a language spec, but I'm not sure where this should perhaps be specified?

More info:

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 9.0.2
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 3.4.0.0
compiled using version 3.4.0.0 of the Cabal library
```

**cabal.project**:

```
packages: myproject/

source-repository-package
    type: git
    location: https://github.com/Plutonomicon/plutarch-plutus.git
    tag: 01a67f56b2bf428538e92ed9ada0ce88d90ab636
```

Comment: Could you try with the latest cabal 3.8.1)?

Comment: Also, slow your .cabal file.

Comment: Also, GHC2021 appeared in GHC 9.2, so you'll likely have to update your GHC to 9.2 (at least) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed when updating GHC to 9.4.3 and cabal to 3.6.2.