# "conflict: requires ImportQualifiedPost" error in cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am trying to get my code to run on my teammates computer.
but I keep getting the following error:

```
 Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[0] next goal: compiler-construction (user goal)
[0] rejecting: compiler-construction-0.1.0.0 (conflict: requires
ImportQualifiedPost)
[__0] fail (backjumping, conflict set: compiler-construction)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: compiler-construction
```

Here is the cabal file we use:

```
cabal-version:      2.4
name:               compiler-construction
version:            0.1.0.0
 
extra-source-files:
  CHANGELOG.md
  README.md
 
library SPLParser
  exposed-modules:
    SPLData
    SPLParser
    SPLPrettyPrinter
    SPLTypeInference
 
  hs-source-dirs:     lib
  build-depends:
    , base        ^>=4.16
    , megaparsec  ^>=9.3.0
    , text        ^>=1.2.5.0
    , containers
 
  default-language:   Haskell2010
  default-extensions:
    ImportQualifiedPost
    OverloadedStrings
    RecordWildCards
 
executable compiler-construction
  main-is:            Main.hs
 
  build-depends:
    , base        ^>=4.16.4.0
    , megaparsec  ^>=9.3.0
    , SPLParser
    , text        ^>=1.2.5.0
 
  hs-source-dirs:     app
  default-language:   Haskell2010
  default-extensions:
    ImportQualifiedPost
    OverloadedStrings
    RecordWildCards
 
test-suite parser-tests
  type:               exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is:            ParserTests.hs
  build-depends:
    , base              ^>=4.16
    , hspec-megaparsec
    , HUnit             ^>=1.6
    , megaparsec        ^>=9.3.0
    , SPLParser
    , text              ^>=1.2.5.0
 
  hs-source-dirs:     tests
  default-language:   Haskell2010
  default-extensions:
    ImportQualifiedPost
    OverloadedStrings
    RecordWildCards
```

It works fine on mine and a friend's machine, but I'm totally stumped on why it won't work on my teammates. We are both using windows subsystem for Linux.

I feel like we are missing something simple. hopefully you can help us out.

Comment: did you both run `cabal update` to load the list of packages and dependencies?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem We used cabal update, install, run and build in almost every order imaginable.

Comment: Which GHC version is your teammate using? [`ImportQualifiedPost`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/import_qualified_post.html) is an extension that was added in GHC 8.10.1, so an older GHC version might cause that. (For a similar situation, see: [*cabal build fails with (conflict: requires GHC2021) it's unclear what this is?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74705986/2751851))

Comment: Of course, `base ^>=4.16` means GHC 9.2, so if teammate is using GHC older than 8.10 they can't use this package anyway, regardless of `ImportQualifiedPost`. Would that show up as a conflict too, or does the unsupported extension conflict block it from even considering the dependency versions?